# Writing script that creates PostGIS view?

Tags: qgis, postgis

Is there any way to create common PostGIS views (e.g. buffers, intersections, differences) by using script-created dialog boxes. A GUI for doing spatial analysis based on PostGIS would be quite helpful for users with no SQL skills.

Example 'Buffer':

[image]

[image]

```
CREATE VIEW test_schema.buffer_bus_stops AS
SELECT
    row_number() over() AS gid,
    ST_Buffer(geom, 100)::geometry(Polygon, /*SRID*/) AS geom
FROM test_schema.bus_stops;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is it possible to create PostGIS views by using scripts? Has anyone done this so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run any SQL on a connected database. Create a script:

```
##Run SQL=name
##dbname=string 
##mysql=string 
outputs_QGISPOSTGISEXECUTESQL_1=processing.runalg('qgis:postgisexecutesql', dbname,mysql)
```

When run, this will give you a dialogue box where you can add the database name and the SQL statement.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that works just fine. But how can users without SQL skills create queries by using drop-down lists, checkboxes and radio buttons? May I ask you to post an example?

Comment: That is a different question to your original posting.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want a "wizard" to let you write SQL?

There is a plugin called **PostGIS Query Builder** which does just that... see [cheatsheet here](https://geogear.wordpress.com/postgisquerybuilder-v1-6-cheatsheet/). It seems to allow gradual building up of queries, and allows creation of views as an option.

Not used it in too much depth, but it sounds like what you're after.

See further down for details on installation... it didn't work 'out of the box', not for me anyway.

---

[image: postgis query builder]

---

[image: postgis query builder]

---

Note, if you're on Ubuntu you might need to install Qt Postgres bindings using

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-sql-psql
```

or you'll get a "Driver not loaded" message. See [this issue on the Github issues page](https://github.com/enricofer/postgisQueryBuilder/issues/15).

I have no idea if it works on Windows/Mac.

Comment: I'm looking for a GUI to create SQL queries. Unfortunately it's not possible to use the PostGIS Query Builder in the graphical modeler. Therefore, I would prefer a script based 'wizard'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe also take a look at the QGIS Plugin called PostGIS Geoprocessing Tools:

https://github.com/NaturalGIS/postgis_geoprocessing

But as with all these 'wrappers' I wonder why the user doesn't just use the existing QGIS geoprocessing tools, as I don't really think PostGIS was designed to replace these tools... it's meant for use in SQL queries!

Comment: Unfortunately the PostGIS geoprocessing tools do not support views. There is no way to create dynamic layers using the existing QGIS geoalgorithims.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to achieve this without writing code, but if you want to create a Python script to create views in PostgreSQL/PostGIS by using drop-down menus for pre-programmed SQL, you could use the Python library psycopg2. You could use python variables as table names, etc.

Take a look at the docs here: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/

Then you could create a plugin for QGIS, use a custom designed form (using QT Designer) in which the user chooses some parameters.